# Update PO status by SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am  trying to update the PO status from 'r' to 'c'

Below is the extraction query.

```
update purchase_order 
set status = 'c'
where STATUS = 'r' and order_date < '2019-01-01';
```

[image: error message]

It was ok to update but now it appears the error message. I wonder what happened?

Comment: You should update your question and correct `purchase_order` to `purc_order_line` since that's the table you're actually trying to run the query against.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the example `select` gives all of the rows you want to change and none of the rows you don't:

```
update purchase_order 
set status = 'c'
where STATUS = 'r' and order_date < '2020-01-01';
```

You have to do this in a separate statement from the `select` query.

Comment: Thank you Joel.  Is this the completed query: select purchase_order.ID, order_date, status 
from purchase_order 
where STATUS = 'r' and order_date < '2019-01-01'
update purchase_order 
set status = 'c'
where STATUS = 'r' and order_date < '2019-01-01';

Comment: @LuZhang No, it's a separate statement. SQL only lets you do one kind of thing at a time. You can't both retrieve data and update it in the same statement.

Answer (score 0):

SSMS will default to the `master` table.  There are settings to change that, but I suspect in this case, your problem is that the query is not being run against the correct database.

You can change the database from `master` to the correct one using the SSMS UI (there's a drop down to select the database the query runs against), OR, incorporate a `USE` statement with your query:

```
USE [database_name]
GO

UPDATE PURCH_ORDER_LINE
SET [status] = 'c'
WHERE [status] = 'r' and order_date < '2019-01-01'

GO
```